# What are the answers to the riddles?

Tags: riddle-story-of-devil

In Akuma No Riddle, each episode contains one riddle - Usually In the episode title or texted to Azuma.

[image]

Haru and Azuma figure some out, but as far as I know, not all the questions are answered.

I might have just overlooked them though...

1. What is the World is Full of? (Haru answers" forgiveness")
2. What's in your heart? (Azuma answers "Blood")
3. What's Red, But Isn't Red?
4. What Comes Suddenly and Never Leaves?
5. What do you need in order to let a caged bird free?
6. Beautiful Flowers Have Their _________?
7. What Can Never Be Caught Up To?
8. Which Gatekeeper is the Liar?
9. What Dwells In Your Heart? (Make-up Test)
10. Who Is The Queen?
11. How to Distinguish a Congratulation from a Curse?
12. Therefore, the World is Full of __________?

What are the answers to the riddles?

Comment: Also at some later ep he mentions that there are not true answer to any of the riddles other than what your hearth gives you or something.

Comment: Number 11 seems like a play on the two kanji. My answer would be `礼` (thanks/gratitude/blessing) or [`礻`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A6%AE) (altar). `祝` (a congratulation) and `呪` (a curse) share the same kanji, 兄 (brother[older]/a close elder figure). Celebrations/thanks are basically a prayer for happiness.

Comment: Number 4 can not be death or curse because it is clear that the love do suddenly comes and it can never leave. This question involves with Suzu Shuto and the password of the bomb was her past love. That shows that love never leaves no matter how long ago it is. It is also obvious that love suddenly comes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid spoilers. As Prix mentioned, there are no definitive answers to the riddles. The answers that Haru and Tokaku come up with are simply "their own answers." The riddles are presented to Tokaku in situations where she fills in the Riddles with answers that have been decided based on her current situation and mental state.

```
1. What is the World Full of? (Haru answers" forgiveness")
11. Therefore, the World is Full of ______?
```

One might answer "lies" for the second, while Haru answers "forgiveness" for the first. However both Haru and Tokaku's situation and mental state are drastically different. 1. being a sort of happy/mellow situation with her class mates, 11. being dramatic and sad due to the prior events.

Answer (score 2):

> Episode 01 - The world is full of ____? = Forgiveness
>
> Episode 02 - What dwells in your heart? = Courage
>
> Episode 03 - What's red, but isn't red? = Blood
>
> Episode 04 - What comes suddenly and never leaves? = Death
>
> Episode 05 - How do you get a bird out of its cage? = Make it trust you
>
> Episode 06 - Every pretty flower has ____? = Thorns
>
> Episode 07 - What can you never outrun? = Time
>
> Episode 08 - Which gatekeeper is the one who lies? = The one who don't tell the truth
>
> Episode 09 - What dwells in your heart? (Make-up Test) = Love
>
> Episode 10 - Who's the queen? = Haru Ichinose
>
> Episode 11 - How to tell apart felicitation from a curse? = ???
>
> Episode 12 - Therefore, the world is full of ____? = Lies

[Reference](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1164381#sHY5XYTHcvzJ2MkF.99)

Comment: For the 5th one, I think the answer is to "kill it", like Tokaku's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not putting questions just what I think should be the answers to this.

1. The world is full of "lies."
2. regret.
3. blood.
4. a curse.
5. open the cage door.
6. Every pretty flower has its "end."
7. death.
8. the one who speaks of everything but the truth.
9. (make-up test) love
10. Haru
11. a curse is as spell that's like Carma and a felicitation is a congratulation.
12. Therefore, the world is full of "hate."

Comment: Why do you think these are correct, rather than the other answer with the list? :o